# Autocomplete incremental search behaviour

Tags: search

**Consider the following scenario**

Content of the buffer:

```
I saw the water in a thermal bath.
```

Commands issued:

`:set incsearch`

`/th^R^W^R^W^R^W^R^W`

**Result**

`thewaterIII`

**Question**

What exactly is the algorithm of the incremental search autocomplete in this case? Why does it behave in such a strange way?

In particular:

- why does it add `water` without a space?
- why does it add only the first `I` letter of the next word `in`?
- why is that letter capitalized?
- why does it get stuck there and does not proceed further?

I would have expected something like this:

`^R^W the`

`^R^W^R^W the water`

`^R^W^R^W^R^W the water in`

`... etc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why does it add water

`C-r C-w` inserts the word positioned under your cursor; however, if `'incsearch'` is set, and there is a match in the buffer for the current contents of the command-line, Vim doesn't use the cursor position anymore, but the end of the match.  From `:h c^r^w`:

```
When 'incsearch' is set the cursor position at the end of the
currently displayed match is used.
```

When your command-line contains `the`, the end of the match is here:

```
I saw the water in a thermal bath.
         ^
```

There is no word at that position, so Vim inserts the next word which is `water`.
I guess Vim uses a similar algorithm as with the [`*` command](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#star):

```
*                       Search forward for the [count]'th occurrence of the
                        word nearest to the cursor.  The word used for the
                        search is the first of:
                                1. the keyword under the cursor |'iskeyword'|
                                2. the first keyword after the cursor, in the
                                   current line
                                3. the non-blank word under the cursor
                                4. the first non-blank word after the cursor,
                                   in the current line
                        Only whole keywords are searched for, like with the
                        command "/\<keyword\>".  |exclusive|
                        'ignorecase' is used, 'smartcase' is not.
```

> without a space?

I guess that's because `C-r C-w` is meant to insert a word, and a space character is not considered as being part of a word.

> why does it add only the first I letter of the next word in?

It's not the first letter of the next word; it's the word under your cursor.

```
I saw the water in a thermal bath.
^
```

When your search command-line contains `thewater`, Vim can't use the end of the match as the position of the word because there is no match for `thewater` in your buffer; so it falls back to your cursor position.
And under your cursor, the word is `I`, not `in`.

> why is that letter capitalized?

Again, it's not just a capitalized letter; it's the word under your cursor.

> why does it get stuck there and does not proceed further?

Because no matter how many `I` you insert, there is still no match in the buffer; so Vim keeps using the cursor position to decide which word to insert.

---

To insert multiple words from the current line, you could also:

1. press `C-r C-l` to insert the whole contents of the line (see [`:h c^r^l`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-L))
2. use traditional editing commands to remove the words you're not interested in (see [`:h ex-edit-index`](https://vimhelp.org/index.txt.html#ex-edit-index))

Note that `c^r^l` requires the patch [`8.0.1787`](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.1787).  Without, you could try some custom mapping (e.g. `cno <c-r><c-l> <c-r><c-r>=getline('.')<cr>`).

Answer (score 3):

[user938271's great answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22539/343) already answers your explicit questions about what happens when you press <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> during an incremental search.

I just wanted to suggest that you might want to try pressing <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> instead. During a search with `'incsearch'` set, this adds the next character after the current match each time it is pressed.

So with your example, typing:

```
/th^L^L^L^L^L^L^L
```

Will result in:

```
/the water
```

(You can of course hold down the keys to auto-repeat.)

See [`:help /_CTRL-L`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%2F_CTRL-L) for more details.